# UIViewController Freeform size issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uipopovercontroller

I am using this amazing PopupViewController (https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController) control. My app uses storyboards.
I have created a custom Segue as per developers instruction(https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController/issues/8) and changed the UIViewController size property to Freeform and re sized it smaller than full screen. But when it called, it shows full screen.
Code for custom Segue is below
    #import "PopupSegue.h"

```
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"

@implementation PopupSegue

- (void)perform {
    [self.sourceViewController presentPopupViewController:self.destinationViewController    animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
}

@end
```

What I am doing wrong? Also is there any better open source PopupViewController with storyboard support?

Comment: Auto layout results in such deviations...just a guess

Comment: I am not using Auto layout in my project

Comment: If you don't have autolayout enabled, check the auto-resizing masks.

Comment: I didn't set any auto-resizing masks.

Answer (score 3):

I need to uncheck option "Resize View From NIB" in your View Controller's Attributes Inspector