# "Freeform" size in IB - Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

As I understand and tried, if I change the simulated size of the ViewController in the storyboard it will still stretch its main "view" property to the whole screen.

So my question is when and why should I change this "Freeform" property?
Whenever I needed to make some overlay, I just make the main "view" transparent and create another view on top of that with my content, then I present it I do it as a container.
As I see there is no need for it, And I couldn't find anywhere in Apple documentation about it.

Comment: Never noticed it before) Perhaps its just a way to have an idea of how your interface will look like on different screens, I mean, who knows what screen resolution will iPhone6 have? Especially if you use auto layouts.

Answer (score 3):

This property is only for **simulating** a different size.
ViewControllers do not always have to be fullscreen containers, for example [View Controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html), or the new iOS 7 View Controller [transitions](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) may lead to a View Controller that's size covers some partial area of the screen.
You would use the 'freeform' mode to change the size in interface builder, so you can **simulate** what the end size would be, whilst you work with it.

Comment: your first statement in your very first sentence **is not** correct at all and highly misleading. where did you get that idea...?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the Q [UIViewController Freeform size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046981/uiviewcontroller-freeform-size-issue): uncheck "Resize View From NIB" in your View Controller's Attributes Inspector and your freeform view controller's view will indeed be decoded at the size you designed in your storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

You are not quite on the right track. If you use `Freeform` for the size of the view controller, you can specify the desired size of your controller.

Also it's really important how you use the controller, how you set the `springs & struts` or `layout constraints`. If you set the springs or constraints to stretch your controller's view to "match" the parent size then the view will be stretched, if not it will keep the size you mentioned but not in all cases. For example if you present the view controller modally and you specify a different `explicit size` in IB then the view will have this size.

Usually you use the `freeform` property when you add the view controller as a child to another view controller programatically and you really want to have that fixed size.

If you push the view controller or you present it as modal view controller (and you use the modal presentation styles) then there is no need to use `freeform`.

Also another use of the `freeform` property is to preview the actual size of your view controller when is presented as a modal view controller using existent presentation styles.

Another wrongly implementation that I seen before regarding the size of the view controller's view is to check the size in `viewDidLoad`. Always check the size in `viewWillAppear|| viewDidAppear`.