# UIViewController Free Form

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My application is for iPad on landscape.

I create a freeform UIViewController (width = 1024, height = 638) to add in a UIPageViewController.

In the ViewDidLoad, or ViewDidAppear of the freeform UIViewController, I have checked the height, its value still is 768?

```
CGFloat yy1 = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat yy2 = self.view.bounds.size.height;

//- yy1 = yy2 = 768f
```

Why is that?

Comment: It's right. What's the problem?

Comment: the value should be 638.

Comment: Do you use any constraint?

Comment: No, I don't use any.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046981/uiviewcontroller-freeform-size-issue) solved my problem.

I need to uncheck option "Resize View From NIB" in your View Controller's Attributes Inspector